# React Bootstrap: Input field along with ref

Tags: react-bootstrap

How to use `react-bootstrap` `<Input>` with `ref`.

```
import { Input } from 'react-bootstrap'

<input ref={node => {
      input = node
    }} placeholder="Enter text"/>
```

When I change the above code to the one shown below, the Input field vanishes without any error. Need some help on how to use `react-bootstrap` `<Input> field` along with `ref`

```
<Input type="text" ref={node => {
      input = node
    }} placeholder="Enter text"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There exists something known as Input Wrapper which doesnot have any `type`. Can be done easily. Apologies for disturbing StackOverflow for this.

```
<Input wrapperClassName="wrapper">
    <input className="form-control" ref={node => {
      input = node
    }} placeholder="Enter text"/>
</Input>
```